# wrong output when using a query to populate comboBox

Tags: c#

Im trying to populate a comboBox with the output of a query.
What I get displayed in the comboBox is System.Data.DataRowView
Here's the code that I use:

```
string subConStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Master.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=password";
       string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM MasterTable";
       OleDbDataAdapter dAdapterComB = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, subConStr);
       System.Data.DataTable source = new System.Data.DataTable() ;
       dAdapterComB.Fill(source);
       comboBoxSubject.DataSource = source;
       comboBoxSubject.DisplayMember = "Subjects";
```

Comment: Your query is only returning a field named `Code`, but you told the binder to use `Subjects`; why? That field doesn't exist in the dataset.

Answer (score 5):

There is no column "Subjects" in your data table, so the combo box doesn't know which field to use to display the value in the combo box.  When it can't find the member it just displays .ToString on thew DataRowView

You can try:

```
comboBoxSubject.DisplayMember = "Code";
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the display member to "Code"